# Import excel data into class instances with python

Tags: python, excel

I'm trying to Import data from an excel sheet, into a list of class instances for an RPG game. Currently I am attempting with Pandas, here is the code I have been working with: python 3.7.2

```
import pandas as pd


class potion(object):

    def __init__(self, name, types, effects, value, weight):
        self.name = name
        self.types = types
        self.effects = effects
        self.value = value
        self.weight = weight

df = pd.read_excel('Data/potions.xlsx', sheet_name='None')

potions = df.values.tolist()

print(potions)
```

with an output of:

```
[['Crude Hp Potion', 'Hp Potion', 10, 10, 0.5], ['Hp Potion', 'Hp Potion', 
   25, 50, 1.0], ...]
```

an example of what i'm looking for is the data to be stored something like this, so that each row is its own index of a list of an instance:

```
potions = [potion('Crude Hp Potion', 'Hp Potion', 10, 10, 0.5),
           potion('Hp Potion', ' hp Potion', 25, 50, 1.0)]
```

to achieve that I have attempted:

```
for i in potions[0]:
    potions.append([potion(i)])

print(potions[0].name)
```

and has given me :

```
TypeError: __init__() missing 4 required positional arguments: 'types', 'effects', 'value', and 'weight'
```

The data on the excel sheet that im working with is as follows:

```
                 Name       Type  Effect  Price  Weight
0     Crude Hp Potion  Hp Potion      10     10     0.5
1           Hp Potion  Hp Potion      25     50     1.0
2  Superior Hp Potion  Hp Potion      50    100     1.5
3     Crude Mp Potion  Mp Potion       5      5     0.5
4           Mp Potion  Mp Potion      15     50     1.0
5  Superior Mp Potion  Mp Potion      30    100     1.5
```

I'm not exactly sure what it is that I'm missing, and would appreciate assistance, I can't seem to find anywhere that explains how to do this.
Thank you.

Comment: can you share an example of the excel file?

Comment: There is an example, its at the bottom of the post however. I apologize, I should have put it at the top.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're very close, you just need to unpack all the values from the lists inside your `potion` list. This can be done with an asterisk (`*`). This way, your potion objects will be called as `potion(arg1, arg2, arg3, arg4, arg5)`, which is correct, instead of `potion([arg1, arg2, arg3, arg4, arg5])`, which raises the error you found (since the list represents a single object).

The following code corrects this:

```
class Potion(object): 
def __init__(self, name, types, effects, value, weight):
    self.name = name
    self.types = types
    self.effects = effects
    self.value = value
    self.weight = weight 

df = pd.read_excel('Data/potions.xlsx', sheet_name='None') 

potions = df.values.tolist()
potion_instances = []
for p in potions:
    potion_instances.append(Potion(*p))
```

I took the liberty of modifying your structure a bit. First, give your objects more meaningful names so you don't get confused - `potion` and `potions` are very close, and by convention Python classes are always written in `CamelCase`. Also, it makes more sense to iterate over your list `potions` and append each created `Potion` object into a new list (which I named `potion_instances`). This way you keep the raw data and the code objects separated from one another.