# Making Objects for a Game

Tags: object

I want to create objects with attributes from an excel sheet. I am still learning the basics and have so far been able to create objects based on the workbook, but I want it to be automated.

Using help online I have been able to get this far:

```
import pandas as pd
class Ingredient:
    def __init__(self, name, rarity, type, A, B, C, D, E, total):
        self.name = name
        self.rarity = rarity
        self.type = type
        self.A = A
        self.B = B
        self.C = C
        self.D = D
        self.E = E
        self.total = total
    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.name}({self.rarity}); {self.type}: {self.A}, {self.B}, {self.C}, {self.D}, {self.E} = {self.total}"
    
df = pd.read_excel("Book.xlsx", sheet_name=0)

ingredients = df.values.tolist()

ingredient_instances = []

for i in ingredients:
    ingredient_instances.append(Ingredient(*i))

print(Ingredient(*i))
```

The problem I’m facing is that it only gives me the final item not the whole list like this:

E Brrry(1); Fruit: 0, 0, 0, 0, 5 = 5

Here’s my workbook:

```
Name,Rarity,Type,A,B,C,D,E,Total
A Berry,1,Fruit,6,0,0,0,0,6
B Berry,2,Fruit,0,6,0,0,0,6
C Berry,3,Fruit,0,0,6,0,0,6
D Berry,2,Fruit,0,0,0,6,0,6
E Berry,1,Fruit,0,0,0,0,6,6
```

I want the script to give me a list of objects with the attributes attached so I can use the items in further projects. Ex: A Berry + B Berry = 6A, 6B, and 12 Total.

Comment: What was the point of appending all your objects to `ingredient_instances`, if you're not going to do anything with that list afterwards?

Comment: I used this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55113379/import-excel-data-into-class-instances-with-python  as a launch pad because of similarities. I plan to use the list for more in depth formulae later in the project’s life, but for now I just want to see the list of items as a proof of concept. The reason I appended my objects is because the result was coming out as a normal string of data rather than a data frame as I wanted it